# Build Regression Model with Categorical Variable

Tags: r, regression

Hi I'm new to R and I was hoping someone could give me some tips on building a regression model.  I have some sample data similar to the sample data below which contains categorical variables like the path variable.  I would like to convert these categorical variables to binary variables like the "Transformed Data" shown  below, so I can use them to create a regression model to predict WaitTime based on Volume on each Path.  In python there's a function called getdummies which does this nicely.  If anyone can give me tips on a similar function in r, or a way to build a regression model with categorical variables.  I would greatly appreciate it.  My end goal is to build the regression model and then find the volume value for each path that will minimize WaitTIme.  Any tips on that as well would definitely be appreciated.
Sample Data:

  `Path  WaitTime Volume
  AD_IB  195     3
  GMC_DT 154     4
  CD_ADT 192     2
  Ord_IB 326     1`

Transformed Data:
`AD_IB GMC_DT  CD_ADT  Ord_IB  WaitTime    Volume
     1     0    0      0            195    3
     0     1    0      0            154    4
     0     0    1      0            192    2
     0     0    0      1            326    1`

Comment: How many categories are in Path?  You can check using table(data$Path) or unique(data$Path) if it is a data.frame.  I ask, because from your example, there are no repeated values.  If all you want to do is create dummy variables, then you can just use it as is or create a factor, and then run a model using lm().

Comment: Have you tried what happens if you just add your categorical variable to a model?

Comment: You do not need to do that. The regression functions will automatically create dummy vectors for you. If you do need to see what the regression functions are using "under the hood", then look at `?model.matrix`.

Comment: Beside what people have said, if you still want to do that: `setDT(data)[,AD_IB:= ifelse(Path=="AD_IB", 1, 0)]`

Answer (score 2):

`R` does that automatically for you:

```
set.seed(1)
d <- data.frame(cat = factor(LETTERS[sample(3, 100, TRUE)]), y = rnorm(100))
lm(y ~ cat, d)

#     # Call:
# lm(formula = y ~ cat, data = d)
# 
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)         catB         catC  
#     -0.2385       0.3518       0.2493
```